# how to add continue character comment notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Hello I want to add continue character to php language in notepad++ but I dont know how. 
It shoul looks like:

```
/*
*
*
*/
```

instead of

```
/*         


*/
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'continue character' ? Please - be more clear.

Comment: you start comment with /* and when you press enter in new line should be * like in NetBeans

Comment: I don't think it is possible with Notepad++.

Comment: it is in define user language you have this option but I want to add it to existing language

Comment: @GiamPy it is possible in a second using multiline cursor, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

double slash // for uncoment per line

Toggle single line comment in Notepad++

Comment: Select the text you want to uncomment, right click and then Toggle single line comment.

You can also use #, you can uncomment one line at a time by adding a # in front, but this must be done manually one by one.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

1. position the cursor to first row in comment which is missing `*` character
2. press <kbd>LeftAlt+Shift+Down</kbd> until you reach last row missing `*` character. You now see cursor blinking over all lines which need to add `*`.
3. type `*` character

for reverse effect (to remove `*`), in step 3 press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd>